# Oracle BPM Ajax to Fuego Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle, business-process-management

I have a specific requirement to have autocomplete in an Oracle BPM project.  I have been trying to figure out the best way to achieve this activity.  I have a good foundation of jQuery and auto-complete.  What way do you find yourself satisfing these types of requirements?

I would like to get the response straight from the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using JSPs to present your BPM Object:

First, define your BPM Object method to receive one single argument of type `String[][String]` (http parameters of the request), and returning `String` (the content of your response).

Then, in your JSP/JavaScript, use Fuego tag "" to get the URL to which you will do an XHR request.

Example, with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
     url: "<f:invokeUrl var='${viewObject}' methodName='loadCandidates'/>",
    data: xhrArgs,
dataType: "text",
 success: function(data, status) {
     /* your code here. data contains the String
        returned   by your method */
 }
});
```

Where `viewObject` is the bpm object variable you are passing to the JSP page.

For details on the tag libs see:
[OBPM JSP Tag lib](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13154_01/bpm/docs65/taglib/index.html).